# is there any way to run all the UI test method in a class?

Tags: c#, xamarin, nunit, coded-ui-tests

I have written UI test for xamarin mobile app in C# using the tool visual studio 2015, I just wanted to know whether I can run all the UI test methods in a single class. I have written all the test in different methods in different classes

Comment: Have you had a look at http://nunit.org/docs/2.5.10/consoleCommandLine.html? There are all options to run tests, also to run all tests within a fixture.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, thanks for your reply. I'm new to visual studio, where to find the nunit console to run the commands

Comment: Can you show your test-code? So you´re using the NUnit-framework that comes with Visual Studio? There are several nunits, that´s why I asked.

Comment: Yes, I'm using NUnit 2.6.4 that comes with visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

In `NUnit.Runners.2.6.x` you can use `-run=XXXX` to specify which tests/fixtures/namespaces to run:

```
-run=STR  Name of the test case(s), fixture(s) or namespace(s) to run
```

i.e.

```
packages/NUnit.Runners.2.6.4/tools/nunit-console.exe -run=Tests iOS_UITest.UITests/bin/Debug/Xamarin.UITest.dll
```

> ⚠️
>   Mono current ships with and older version of NUnit that does not support all of the NUnit features that UITests may rely on. You are strongly recommend to use the test runner from Nunit 2.6.3 or higher when running UITests at the command line. **Note that Xamarin.UITest is not compatible with NUnit 3.0.**

re: [Running_UITests_Using_the_Command_Line](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/cheatsheet/#Running_UITests_Using_the_Command_Line)

Comment: I suppose from OPs question that this is what he/she allready has. He wants to run all of them.

Comment: hi @SushiHangover , what is "STR" in the above answer

Comment: @ragesh-ragav1993 Name of the test, or fixture or namespace

Comment: hI @SushiHangover. I am getting the below output when i tried to run the test in nunit console.

Comment: NUnit-Console version 2.6.4.14350
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment -
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
  CLR Version: 2.0.50727.8762 ( Net 3.5 )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: net-3.5
Selected test(s): Create_Activity

Tests run: 0, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 0.00733685179565775
 seconds
  Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0